# ruby class method with decorator

Tags: ruby, decorator

I want to have separate classes with `instant_method` and `class_method` as follow:

```
module ObjReviewModule  ## common methods module
  def own_methods(obj_)
    ruby_methods = " ".methods & 1.methods
    (obj_.methods - ruby_methods).map { |x| x.to_s }
  end

  def specific_methods(obj_,existing_=[])
    self.own_methods(obj_).select { |x| !existing_.include?(x) }
  end
end

class ObjReviewMethod ## instance_method 
  include ObjReviewModule 

  def get_(obj_)
    own_methods(obj_).select { |x| x.start_with?("get") }
  end

  def to_(obj_)
    own_methods(obj_).select{ |x| x.start_with?("to_") }
  end
end

class ObjList < OsObjReviewMethod ## class_method 
  extend ObjReviewModule

  def self.get_methods(obj_)
    # something should be here to make OsObjReviewMethod instance_method became class_method
  end
end
```

I got `ObjReviewMethod` worked as

```
object_methods = ObjReviewMethod.new
object_methods.get_(obj_) => get "own_methods" start with "get" using instance_class_method
ObjList.own_methods(obj_) => get "own_methods" with class_method
```

but i could not figure out how to get `class_method` without rewrite all definitions :

```
ObjList.get_methods(obj_) => get all "own_methods" start with "get" using class_method
```

It would be perfect if  decorator class could use all `instance_method` of base class as `class_method`

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your problem. You want all instance methods of a class to become class methods of another class? If that's all, then you could move all instance methods to a module, include it in one class and extend the other class.

Comment: Thanks for advices. I got same solutions after review module documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solutions as below

```rb
module ObjReviewModule  ## common methods module
  def own_methods(obj_)
    ruby_methods = " ".methods & 1.methods
    (obj_.methods - ruby_methods).map { |x| x.to_s }
  end

  def specific_methods(obj_,existing_=[])
    self.own_methods(obj_).select { |x| !existing_.include?(x) }
  end
end

module ObjReviewMethod 
  include ObjReviewModule 
  def get_(obj_)
    own_methods(obj_).select { |x| x.start_with?("get") }
  end
  def to_(obj_)
    own_methods(obj_).select{ |x| x.start_with?("to_") }
  end
end

class ObjList ## class_method 
  extend ObjReviewModule
  extend ObjReviewMethod
end

class ObjReview ## instance_method 
  include ObjReviewModule
  include ObjReviewMethod
end
```